# PHP MySQL Excel to xls?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

This my example code:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A2', '1.0');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', '0.0');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C2', '1.2');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D2', '100');
```

I am getting in excel sheet is round off values for `A2->1` and `B2->0`, What I need to output in excel sheet is `A2->1.0` and `B2->0.0`. I need the float values end with .zero (`.0`) to print.

Please help me out...

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the display format of the cells to Number.  The default in Excel is General, which will display the values as you describe.  I don't know if the PHP Excel interface will let you set the cell format, but that's where you should start.

EDIT: According to the PHPExcel website it supports setting cell formats. Read the docs to find out how to set the appropriate format.

Answer (score 1):

Export / Import excel to mysql.
[DEAME3P](http://objetivophp.com/?p=89)

Answer (score 1):

I think u want something like this

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('###.00');
```

I use it on my project, any doubts, ask away